# Magento Import of tier prices with SOAP API V2 doesnt work

Tags: api, delphi, magento, soap

hope to get some help here.
I try to create tier prices in Magento for groups using soap api v2.
Currently using version 1.9.0.0 of Magento
Am developing with delphi, using the WSDL.

What i do is the following, looping through the tier prices of my ERP system:

```
mycatalogProductTierPriceEntity := catalogProductTierPriceEntity.Create;
mycatalogProductTierPriceEntity.customer_group_id := group_price_mage_group_id;
mycatalogProductTierPriceEntity.website := IntToStr(Website_ID);
mycatalogProductTierPriceEntity.qty := Round(WINLineArtikelStaffelMenge);
mycatalogProductTierPriceEntity.price := 2.85;//WINLineArtikelStaffelKundenPreis;
mycatalogProductTierPriceEntityArray[j] := mycatalogProductTierPriceEntity;
inc(j);
mycatalogProductTierPriceEntity := nil;
```

Finally I assign my Price Array to the Product Entity:

```
mycatalogProductCreateEntity.tier_price := mycatalogProductTierPriceEntityArray;
```

But the prices wont show in Magento Admin, no error listed… either on creating a product or updating it.
All other fields are updated / created correctly.

I made a test and entered 2 group tier prices in the backend
Both for group “Retailer”

Then i tried to get the product info via soap call “catalogProductInfo”.
On debugging i looked inside the result set and could see my 2 tier prices, but without group specified and without quantity specified,
although i can see that in the backend…

Anybody an idea of what is wrong ?

best regards
Holger

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution on my own... 
All the API calls are totally correct.
But there is a setting in the Magento Administration 
(System->Configuration->Catalog)
where you can define the price range. Default setting is "global" which has to be switched to "website".
Only with this setting, customer group tier prices can be written.